# Match header and values, mutliline using regex

Tags: python, regex, string, matching

I have a document with the following structure:

- A header (some text without any whitespace in the same line)
- A list (could be empty) of values:
- Each value starts with a tab character, and then is text without any whitespaces.

I would like to build a regex pattern such that each match contains 1 header group and 0-n values group.

Here is what I am trying, which I believe it is quite close, but probably some small problem I can't find:

https://regex101.com/r/XSszya/1

```
^(?P<header>[^\s]+)$(?P<value>^\t[^\s]$)*
```

Thanks.

Comment: This should work for you: https://regex101.com/r/XSszya/2 btw you should provide full info in question i.e. attempted regex, sample input and expected matches

Comment: @anubhava I did not see your post, I am on a holiday on a mobile phone (which is quite challenging) You can post it if you want

Comment: @Thefourthbird You have a very good answer ++ mine was just a comment since question didn't have all the info originally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can repeat the second part starting with a newline and a tab.

Then repeat the inner part of the `value` group in its own non capture group to get the whole match in group `value`

```
^(?P<header>\S+)(?P<value>(?:\n\t\S+)*$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HqWTyL/1)